# Scheme (Racket) printing #void

Tags: scheme, racket

I have the following function in Scheme (Using Dr. Racket), it's a vague translator from Scheme to Javascript.

I can't seem to figure out why #void is being printed.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the return value of fprintf, but I'm not sure how can this behavior be overcome.

Any ideas?

```
(define unparse->js
(lambda (ast output-port)
(cond ((def-exp? ast) (fprintf output-port "const ~a = ~a;" (unparse->js 
(def-exp->var ast) output-port) (unparse->js (def-exp->val ast) output-port)))
      ((cexp? ast)
       (cond ((num-exp? ast) (number->string (num-exp->val ast)))
             ((bool-exp? ast) (if (eq? (bool-exp->val ast) #t) "true" "false"))
             ((str-exp? ast)  (str-exp->val ast))
             ((var-exp? ast)  (symbol->string (var-exp->var ast)))
             ((literal-exp? ast) (list 'quote (literal-exp->val ast)))
             ((proc-exp? ast) (fprintf output-port "(~a) => { ~a }"
                                       (string-join
                                        (map (lambda (b)
                                             (unparse->js b output-port)
                                             )
                                           (proc-exp->params ast)
                                       )
                                      ",")
                                       (string-join
                                      (map (lambda (ast)
                                             (unparse->js ast output-port)
                                             )
                                           (proc-exp->body ast))
                                      ";")))

             ((if-exp? ast) (fprintf output-port "~a ? ~a : ~a"
                                     (unparse->js (if-exp->test ast) output-port)
                                     (unparse->js (if-exp->then ast) output-port)
                                     (unparse->js (if-exp->else ast) output-port)))
             ((let-exp? ast) (fprintf output-port "let ~a; ~a;"
                                     (string-join
                                      (map (lambda (b)
                                             (fprintf output-port "~a = ~a"
                                                      (unparse->js (binding->var b) output-port)
                                                      (unparse->js (binding->val b) output-port)
                                                      )
                                             )
                                           (let-exp->bindings ast)
                                       )
                                      ",")
                                     (string-join
                                      (map (lambda (b)
                                             (unparse->js b output-port)
                                             )
                                           (let-exp->body ast))
                                      ";")

                              )
              )
             ((app-exp? ast) (fprintf output-port "~a(~a)"
                                      (unparse->js (app-exp->rator ast) output-port)
                                      (string-join
                                        (map (
                                              lambda (rand)
                                               (unparse->js rand output-port)
                                              )
                                         (app-exp->rands ast)
                                        )
                                        ",")
                              )
              )
             (else (error "Unknown exp type: " ast))))
      (else (error "Unknown exp type: " ast)))
  )
)
```

I'm calling it this way:

> (unparse->js (parse '(if (eq? 5 3) 1 0)) (current-output-port))

The expected result is:

> eq?(5,3) ? 1 : 0

However, the result I'm getting is:

> eq?(5,3) #< void > ? 1 : 0

Answer (score 1):

try printing to a string output port and see if that solves the problem. 
If not produce a complete example we can test. The bug might be in, say, unparse->js or another function.

To figure where the void is printed, insert

```
(displayln ast)
```

Right after

```
 (lambda (ast output-port)
```

Such that the current ast print each time unparse->js is called. Then you can find the clause of the cond that is the culprit.

Regarding the comment more "voids" pop up.

There are two problems: first your output-port is the same as the repl output port. That means that values you don't print (such as in the num-exp clause) are printed by the repl.

Try this

(with-output-to-string
      (lambda () (unparse->js (parse '(if (eq? 5 3) 1 0)) (current-output-port))))

This will make a string containing everything printed.

The second problem is due to this way of printing:

```
 (fprintf output-port "~a ? ~a : ~a"
     (unparse->js (if-exp->test ast) output-port)
     (unparse->js (if-exp->then ast) output-port)
     (unparse->js (if-exp->else ast) output-port)))
```

Since unparse-js returns `void` in all clauses where you use fprintf (remember that fprintf returns `void`) you will print `void` if one of the subexpressions returns `void`.

The question is now how to avoid the problem. A common solution is split the printing in two parts. The first phase is to built a tree of strings. Printing the strings in the string will produce the correct output.

So instead of:

```
 (fprintf output-port "~a ? ~a : ~a"
     (unparse->js (if-exp->test ast) output-port)
     (unparse->js (if-exp->then ast) output-port)
     (unparse->js (if-exp->else ast) output-port)))
```

you write

```
 (list (unparse->js (if-exp->test ast))
       " ? " 
       (unparse->js (if-exp->then ast))
       " : "
       (unparse->js (if-exp->else ast))))
```

This will make `unparse->js` return a tree of strings.

Then simply make a printer function that recurses through the tree and prints the individual strings.

Comment: I apologize for confusing you. The function that's written above IS unparse->js.
Fixed it now.

Comment: What is the result of (parse '(if (eq? 5 3) 1 0))

Comment: '(if-exp (app-exp (var-exp eq?) ((num-exp 5) (num-exp 3))) (num-exp 1) (num-exp 0))

Basically, these "expressions" are translated using another module, that's called "parser"

Comment: Added a new suggestion.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks.

I'm getting the following output:

(if-exp (app-exp (var-exp eq?) ((num-exp 5) (num-exp 3))) (num-exp 1) (num-exp 0))
-|- 
(app-exp (var-exp eq?) ((num-exp 5) (num-exp 3)))-|-
(var-exp eq?)-|-
(num-exp 5)-|-
(num-exp 3)-|-
eq?(5,3)(num-exp 1)-|-
(num-exp 0)-|-
#<void> ? 1 : 0-|-

Although it isn't very readable, so I've added line seperators.

Comment: Look at the clause for num-exp. You forgot to print the value. You simply return it. The same problem is in some of the neigh our clauses.

Comment: Actually it was intended, when adding fprintf over the number in order to print them, more #< void > pops up.

Comment: I have added a discussion of the two problems causing this.